# How to combine a collection that's an object property (for collectionviewsource)

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have a CollectionViewSource that gets bound to an ObservableCollection in a ViewModel, for this we'll call it

```
ObservableCollection<ItemCollection> Items;
```

Now, I have another collection which holds a Collection of Collections that gets updated and returned from a service (the service is updating the actual object, the container is static).

```
ObservableCollection<ItemCollectionContainer> Container;
```

Each "Container" has a property "Items" which has a list.

What I want to display is the complete List of ALL Container.Items put in 1 collection, and if possible, if an items gets added to Container.Items, it gets updated.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can I bump this?  No answers in 2 days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can say is I must fail in explaining what I was looking for of it was so simple, people wanted me to figure it out myself :)

Answer is

```
viewModel.Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(Container.SelectMany(x => x.Items));
```